# Sympy check whether there is a symbol multiplying symbol before simplification

Tags: python, sympy

Hi stackoverflow again,

I'm facing another sympy problem.
I need to check out whether my expression exists symbol * symbol

For instance,

```
parse_expr("abc_mmw", evaluate=False) => valid
parse_expr("abc_mmw * 5", evaluate=False) => valid
parse_expr("abc_mmw + efg_sub6", evaluate=False) => valid
parse_expr("abc_mmw * efg_sub6", evaluate=False) => invalid
parse_expr("abc_mmw / efg_sub6", evaluate=False) => invalid
parse_expr("abc_mmw / abc_mmw", evaluate=False) => invalid (Even though it could be simplifed to 1, it should be filtered out)
```

Since I want to filter out the case like `abc_mmw / abc_mmw`, I cannot set `evaluate=True` in `parse_expr`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days, I came up with the following solution. Just do the tree traversal along with the checking logic

> If the parent node is `Mul` and it has at least two child nodes are `Symbol`.

```
def is_valid(expr):    
    parent_is_mul = expr.func.is_Mul
    i = 0
    for arg in expr.args:
        if(arg.is_Mul):
            return check_mul(arg)
        elif(not arg.is_number and parent_is_mul):
            i += 1
            if (i == 2):
                return False
    return True
```